# get the function called from a C++ code

Tags: c++, lua

for example i have this:

```
static int callFunction(lua_State* L)
{
 int p = lua_gettop(L);
 if (p == 1 && lua_isfunction(L, -1)) {
  /*
   * now i need something like "get the function thats in the first parametre
   */
 }
 return 0;
}
```

now i need to get the function thats in the first parametre of the function in this C++ code, sry for not being clear, i suck at explaining.

Comment: Are you asking how to find a function from a string?

Comment: You might check out the lunar.h implementation - it may have the answer to your question.  http://lua-users.org/wiki/CppBindingWithLunar

Comment: You *have* the function. You've verified that you have one argument, you've verified that that argument is a Lua function, it's sitting there on the stack waiting for you. Now what do you want to *do* with it?

Comment: Exactly, i want to store it in a vector or something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to store a "pointer" to a Lua function in C++, you could just store the /name/ of the Lua function and then do as DeadMG says and call it with `lua_call`, as here: http://pgl.yoyo.org/luai/i/lua_call .

If you are stuck with the code you have already, it's kind of a sticky problem; I'm not sure you can get the name of the Lua function from the stack you have.  In other words, you may need to modify the code one level up from what you posted.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to call the function, you can use lua_call. Lua however won't allow you to take any sort of useful pointer to Lua functions. If you want to store a function in Lua, then you will have to use the Lua registry to store it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you might want to look into the [lua_tocfunction()](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_tocfunction) function.

Comment: What would the index parameter be then?